# C++ constructor query

Tags: c++, oop, time-complexity

I have picked this question from online coding event.I have just tried out to ask a question directly to the point. tell me which one will be better way from this following two?
I have to initialize 10^6 integers.
what will be the better approach from following two:
1) using constructor because I'm not using any loop over here.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long int i = 0;
class Number{
    long int n;
    public:
    Number():n(++i){}
}; 
int main(){
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   Number *ptr;
   ptr = new Number[n];
   return 0;
}
```

2) using for loop:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   long int i,n;
   cin>>n;
   long int *arr;
   arr= new long int[n];

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      *(arr+i) = i+1;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Measure it and find out!

Comment: Does the first one even work? If it does it's very convoluted and unmaintainable

Comment: You'd have to work very hard to convince me that wrapping an integer in a class with no visible value-add is a good idea. As presented it looks like your use case is [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota). I'd start with it and only go with something else only after it's been proved that A) You have to do it and B) the roll-your-own version is noticeably faster.

Comment: Note that just because you don't have any loops doesn't  mean that there aren't any. If you nave to visit N integers to set N values, something is doing the work performing those N visits and you still have a O(N) operation.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes...first one works

Comment: @UnholySheep are you trying to say that both ways are similar ??

Comment: Personally I would use `std::vector<long int> data(n); std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);`